Insufficient funds error during Solana transaction via Jupiter API despite adequate balance
I'm encountering a persistent "Insufficient funds" error when trying to execute a swap using the Jupiter API on the Solana blockchain, even though I have confirmed that the wallet has an adequate balance. Below is the script I'm using, which integrates with the Jupiter swap API to convert SOL to USDT. The error occurs even after adjusting the balance threshold and ensuring enough funds to cover transaction fees and rent exemption. Balance on wallet: 0,09 SOL. Transaction size: 0,0001 SOL
Environment:
Node.js
@solana/web3.js
@solana/spl-token

I increased SOL balance above the required threshold for transaction fees and rent exemption.
Confirmed manually in the Phantom wallet that the swap can be completed with a smaller balance without error.
Checked and re-checked the account creation and balance verification logic in the script.
Despite these adjustments, the script fails to execute the swap without running into an "insufficient funds" error. Manual transactions via the wallet do not encounter this issue.

Program Error: "Instruction #4 Failed - insufficient funds" Program
returned error: custom program error: 0x1

// Fix the require so that can be run locally
require('dotenv').config();
const fetch = require('cross-fetch');
const bs58 = require('bs58');
const {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
  VersionedTransaction,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction
} = require('@solana/web3.js');

const RPC_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com';
const connection = new Connection(RPC_ENDPOINT, 'confirmed');
const payer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY));

const { Token, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } = require('@solana/spl-token');

async function ensureTokenAccountExists(connection, payer, mintAddress) {
    const mintPublicKey = new PublicKey(mintAddress);
    const payerPublicKey = payer.publicKey;

    // Check if the token account already exists
    const tokenAccount = await Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        Token.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        mintPublicKey,
        payerPublicKey
    );

    let tokenAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(tokenAccount);
    if (!tokenAccountInfo) {
        console.log("Token account does not exist, creating one...");
        const transaction = new Transaction().add(
            Token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
                Token.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                mintPublicKey,
                tokenAccount,
                payerPublicKey,
                payerPublicKey
            )
        );

        // Sign and send the transaction to create the token account
        await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer]);
    } else {
        console.log("Token account already exists.");
    }

    // Re-check the balance to ensure it covers rent exemption
    const solBalance = await connection.getBalance(payerPublicKey);
    const minimumRequiredBalance = LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 0.1; // Increased threshold to 0.1 SOL

    if (solBalance < minimumRequiredBalance) {
        console.log("Insufficient SOL to cover transaction fees and rent. Please fund your account.");
        throw new Error("Insufficient funds to proceed.");
    }
}

async function getSwapQuote(inputMint, outputMint, amount, slippageBps = 50) {
    const url = `https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint=${inputMint}&outputMint=${outputMint}&amount=${amount}&slippageBps=${slippageBps}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    return await response.json();
}

async function executeSwap(quoteResponse) {
    console.log("Starting swap execution...");
    const swapResponse = await fetch('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            quoteResponse,
            userPublicKey: payer.publicKey.toString(),
            wrapAndUnwrapSol: false,
        })
    });

    if (!swapResponse.ok) {
        const responseBody = await swapResponse.text();
        console.error(`HTTP error during swap! status: ${swapResponse.status}`);
        console.error("Response body:", responseBody);
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${swapResponse.status}`);
    }

    const responseData = await swapResponse.json();
    if (responseData.error || !responseData.swapTransaction) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to obtain swap transaction: ${responseData.error}`);
    }

    const transactionBuffer = Buffer.from(responseData.swapTransaction, 'base64');
    const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(transactionBuffer);
    transaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getRecentBlockhash()).blockhash;
    transaction.sign([payer]);

    console.log("Transaction details before sending:", JSON.stringify(transaction));

    const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize(), {
        skipPreflight: true,
        preflightCommitment: 'confirmed'
    });

    console.log(`Swap executed, transaction ID: ${txid}`);
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const inputMint = 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112'; // SOL
        const outputMint = 'Es9vMFrzaCERmJfrF4H2FYD4KCoNkY11McCe8BenwNYB'; // USDT
        const amount = 0.0001 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;

        console.log(`Attempting to swap ${amount / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL} SOL to USDT...`);
        const quoteResponse = await getSwapQuote(inputMint, outputMint, amount);
        console.log("Quote response:", JSON.stringify(quoteResponse, null, 2));

    if (!quoteResponse.error) {
      await executeSwap(quoteResponse);
    } else {
      console.error('Failed to get a swap quote:', quoteResponse.error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
  }
})();

When I run the script, here's the output I receive:
Attempting to swap 0.0001 SOL to USDT...
Quote response: {
  "inputMint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
  "inAmount": "100000",
  "outputMint": "Es9vMFrzaCERmJfrF4H2FYD4KCoNkY11McCe8BenwNYB",
  "outAmount": "14644",
  "otherAmountThreshold": "14571",
  "swapMode": "ExactIn",
  "slippageBps": 50,
  "platformFee": null,
  "priceImpactPct": "0",
  "routePlan": [
    {
      "swapInfo": {
        "ammKey": "Bev3s1WZtmvfSspWmkpfvaBz2vCB3ckqm5SLVtVJiDPF",
        "label": "Raydium CLMM",
        "inputMint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
        "outputMint": "7dHbWXmci3dT8UFYWYZweBLXgycu7Y3iL6trKn1Y7ARj",
        "inAmount": "100000",
        "outAmount": "84914",
        "feeAmount": "9",
        "feeMint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"
      },
      ...
    }
  ],
  "contextSlot": 261029705,
  "timeTaken": 0.006935252
}

Starting swap execution...
Transaction details before sending: {"signatures": [{"0":243,"1":85,...},{"message": {"header":...
Swap executed, transaction ID:


I had faced a similar issue and what I found the problem to be is while converting to string sometimes the value is not accurate.
body: JSON.stringify({quoteResponse, userPublicKey: payer.publicKey.toString(), wrapAndUnwrapSol: false})
This line you are using might be causing issue while converting the values of quoteResponse.
Also you have wrapAndUnwrapSol set as false. Which means for the swap it will require wSOL(Wrapped SOL) to already be present in your wallet. The wallet will also require regular SOL for paying the fees of the transaction.
Are you sure you have wSOL present in your wallet? If not, simply change the wrapAndUnwrapSol condition to true.

thank you! It was really helpful.
Here's the part of the code that was crucial:
const postData = JSON.stringify({
quoteResponse: quoteResponse, // Ensuring this field was named as expected by the API
userPublicKey: payer.publicKey.toString(),
wrapAndUnwrapSol: true  // Changed based on your suggestion to handle wrapping automatically
});

@Val Glad was able to help you. It would be great if you approve my answer so that anyone else who requires help won't be confused

Here is the correct function that works well:
async function executeSwap(quoteResponse) {
    console.log("Starting swap execution...");

    // Ensure that the data structure matches the API's expected schema
    const postData = JSON.stringify({
        quoteResponse: quoteResponse, // This field must be named exactly as expected by the API
        userPublicKey: payer.publicKey.toString(),
        wrapAndUnwrapSol: true
    });

    const swapResponse = await fetch('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: postData
    });

    if (!swapResponse.ok) {
        const responseBody = await swapResponse.text();
        console.error(`HTTP error during swap! status: ${swapResponse.status}`);
        console.error("Response body:", responseBody);
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${swapResponse.status}`);
    }

    const responseData = await swapResponse.json();
    if (responseData.error || !responseData.swapTransaction) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to obtain swap transaction: ${responseData.error}`);
    }

    const transactionBuffer = Buffer.from(responseData.swapTransaction, 'base64');
    const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(transactionBuffer);
    transaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getRecentBlockhash()).blockhash;
    transaction.sign([payer]);

    console.log("Transaction details before sending:", JSON.stringify(transaction));

    const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize(), {
        skipPreflight: true,
        preflightCommitment: 'confirmed'
    });

    console.log(`Swap executed, transaction ID: ${txid}`);
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
